# I get n/a in columns when using the pivot_wider function

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]

when I execute the following code:

```r
data_ikea_wider <- data_ikea_longer %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Record_no
                          , Geography
                          , City
                          , Country
                          , City.Country
                          , Year)
                          , names_from = Category, values_from = Value)
```

The columns just have n/a's as shown in the attached print screen.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please can you use ``dput(head(data))`` and edit your question to include the output rather than posting a screenshot. People can't reproduce your error from a screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some reproducible data please? It's hard to say without seeing any of your data.

Comment: `NA`s are common when not every column-to-be is included within each group of `id_cols`.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help! :) I am new to this so next time I will add more info when posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, col1 ~ col2, value.var = 'val')
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting `NA`s from a pivot is not unexpected, it means that not all of your id columns have all "columns".

For example,

```r
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,2), col2 = c('a', 'b', 'a'), val = 1:3)
dat
#   col1 col2 val
# 1    1    a   1
# 2    1    b   2
# 3    2    a   3
```

If we want to pivot keeping `col1` as an id, and turning `col2` values into new columns, then it should be apparent that we'll end up with two rows (ida `1` and `2`), and two new columns (`a` and `b`) to replace `col2` and `val`. Unfortunately, since we only have three rows, the 2 rows 2 columns = 4 cells will not be completely filled with 3 values, so one will be `NA`:

```r
pivot_wider(dat, col1, names_from = col2, values_from = val)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#    col1     a     b
#   <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     2
# 2     2     3    NA
```

If you see this and are surprised, thinking that you actually have the data ... then you should check your data importing and filtering to make sure you did not inadvertently remove it (or it was not provided initially).